# Identify MySQL create version from data files

Tags: mysql

Someone has given me a copy of a database full of FRM, MYD, and MYI files.  Trying to open it in my newer MySQL version gives an error that I need to run mysql_upgrade.  I don't want to change the files at all, so I want to install the same version of MySQL that was used to create the database.  Is there some way to identify the creation version from looking at these files?

Comment: You might be able to run it with the --upgrade-system-tables option. This should leave the user-defined schemas alone. Please see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html Always back up the original files first before you run something and you can always restore from the backups if what you try doesn't work.

Comment: Also, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files

Comment: @raphael75 - That sounds backwards.  The frm/myd/myi files _in the database_ probably need fixing, not the system tables.

Comment: Do you have the mysql schema (`user.MYD`, `user.MYI`, ...) ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the .frm file with a hex editor. Go to offset 0x33 and read four bytes. Convert to decimal, keeping your endianness in mind.

**Examples**:

- `c0c30000` --> `c3c0` --> `50112` --> version `5.1.12`
- `64c50000` --> `c564` --> `50532` --> version `5.5.32`
- `b2860100` --> `186b2` --> `100018` --> version `10.0.18` (MariaDB)
- `19870100` --> `18719` --> `100121` --> version `10.1.21` (MariaDB)

**Sources**:

- [MySQL Internals Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html)
- [a percona.com blog entry](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/07/09/obtain-mysql-version-frm-file/)